# Updating a Dataset to add calculated fields

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a dataset see below:

```
SELECT jockey.jockey_skey
, raceresults.place 
FROM   jockey 
       INNER JOIN runnersandriders 
               ON jockey.jockey_skey = runnersandriders.jockey_skey 
       INNER JOIN horse 
               ON runnersandriders.horse_skey = horse.horse_skey 
       INNER JOIN raceresults 
               ON horse.horse_skey = raceresults.horse_skey 
GROUP  BY jockey.jockey_skey, 
          raceresults.place 
ORDER  BY jockey.jockey_skey
```

This provides me with:

```
Jockey_Skey    Place
1              01
1              04
2              03
2              04
3              02
3              02
```

What I want to do is count how many races a Jockey has ran and the list where they have come.

So Jockey 1, Raced 2 times, Come 1st once and 4th once so on so forth but for the life of me I cannot remember how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this to get the results for each jockey in one row:

```
SELECT  jockey.jockey_skey,
        TotalRaces = COUNT(*),
        [1sts] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '01' THEN 1 END),
        [2nds] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '02' THEN 1 END),
        [3rds] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '03' THEN 1 END),
        [4ths] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '04' THEN 1 END),
        [5ths] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '05' THEN 1 END),
        [6ths] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '06' THEN 1 END),
        [7ths] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '07' THEN 1 END),
        [8ths] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = '08' THEN 1 END),
        -- etc
        [NonRunner] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = 'NR' THEN 1 END),
        [Fell] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = 'F' THEN 1 END),
        [PulledUp] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = 'PU' THEN 1 END),
        [Unseated] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = 'U' THEN 1 END),
        [Refused] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = 'R' THEN 1 END),
        [BroughtDown] = COUNT(CASE WHEN raceresults.place = 'B' THEN 1 END)
FROM    jockey 
        INNER JOIN runnersandriders 
            ON jockey.jockey_skey = runnersandriders.jockey_skey 
        INNER JOIN horse 
            ON runnersandriders.horse_skey = horse.horse_skey 
        INNER JOIN raceresults 
            ON horse.horse_skey = raceresults.horse_skey 
GROUP  BY jockey.jockey_skey
ORDER  BY jockey.jockey_skey
```

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e24a0/9)**

ALternatively you could use `WITH ROLLUP` to get an additional row with totals:

```
SELECT  jockey.jockey_skey,
        raceresults.place,
        [CountOfResult] = COUNT(*)
FROM    jockey 
        INNER JOIN runnersandriders 
            ON jockey.jockey_skey = runnersandriders.jockey_skey 
        INNER JOIN horse 
            ON runnersandriders.horse_skey = horse.horse_skey 
        INNER JOIN raceresults 
            ON horse.horse_skey = raceresults.horse_skey 
GROUP  BY jockey.jockey_skey, raceresults.place
WITH ROLLUP
ORDER  BY jockey.jockey_skey, raceresults.place;
```

Where `NULL` values represent totals

**[Simplified Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e24a0/8)**

Comment: Hi Gareth option 1 would be perfect but my Place field is a Varchar(50) this because I have things like NR, PU etc so the the first option gives me the error message

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NR' to data type int.

Comment: You just need to place the number inside quotes e.g. '01`, or '1'. I've edited the answer to include more possible outcomes